# EE Video Plugins

Tags: ee2, members

Can anyone advise if any of the available EE plugins to embed YouTube etc into a page, will also embed into the EE forum software as a WYSIWYG so that members can use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the [Channel Videos module from DevDemon](http://www.devdemon.com/expressionengine-addons/channel-videos) with YouTube and Vimeo videos. It has a lookup feature within the module so you can search either resource from your EE install..quite good, and it's free. One issue: name your video tab anything other than {video} - that fails for some reason.

Comment: The main thing that I am looking for is for forum users to be able to place videos in their posts.
Will this setup do that job ?

Comment: Sure - you can also wire it to the template with the stand alone entry form and safecracker. That said, if all you need is to allow users to pass a video link to your website and display that YouTube element on the page, you can do that with just a simple text field...use the YouTube sharing link for such things...

Comment: Magic ! That tells me just what I needed to know. I am still a complete Newbie to EE and still feeling my way around.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: No worries - ask away, but please do remember to mark the question as answered.  ;)

Comment: OK, will do !
Still fumbling around my new EE forum installation. Over the years I have played with numerous CMS/website building doftware, and free forum software. Having it all under one cPanel will eventually make it all much more efficient.

Comment: How do I mark this item as answered ?

Comment: You should see a potential checkmark under the down arrow..check it out:

http://stackoverflow.com/tour